# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_netinfo.default.isConnected.fetch')

Tags: react-native

I want to get connection status in my `react-native` app so when there is no internet, I get an alert box with message, `"check your connection and retry later"`

For that reason, I included `netInfo` in my app:

```js
CheckConnectivity = () => {
   // For Android devices
   if (Platform.OS === "android") {
       NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
         if (isConnected) {
            Alert.alert("You are online!");
          } else {
            Alert.alert("You are offline!");
          }
       });
    } else {
       // For iOS devices
       NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
          "connectionChange",
          this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
       );
     }
};
    
handleFirstConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
       "connectionChange",
       this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
    
    if (isConnected === false) {
       Alert.alert("You are offline!");
    } else {
       Alert.alert("You are online!");
    }
};
     
<Button
  onPress={() => this.CheckConnectivity()}
  title="Check Internet Connectivity"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

But when I execute my code, I get this error (below):

[image]

Comment: Which version of react native are you using??

Comment: "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",

Comment: You are using 0.61.4. Netinfo is  remove from react-native 0.60.0. You can also check this react native change log https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0600. Community create seperated package for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener() has been `deprecated` for a year and was removed in the last major update 0.62. You need to update your code and install `npm i @react-native-community/netinfo`.

**Import the library:**

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
```

**Subscribe to network state updates:**

**Subscribe**

```
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {

  console.log("Connection type", state.type);

  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);

});
```

**Unsubscribe**

```
unsubscribe();
```